# Mapping columns without knowing what's in the table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query-performance

I have an odd situation where I will have data coming from various sources (all flat files, none of which are in my control, and no matter how many times I ask for a standard format, I get different column headers and different column orders). We do not have the manpower to manually go through these files to determine which columns are important. Each flat file will have between two and six "identification" columns. However, some of the columns, individually, are not unique, but their combinations can form unique keys. All told, each flat file can have somewhere around one hundred columns.

So, initially, I planned to load the data into a temp table and ask the user to identify which columns contained which data. Once I know that, I can process the file without issue. I would have the two to six columns to identify matches with existing records and the additional data that I am supposed to gather (all identified by the user).

I was then asked to add in the ability for the system to "recommend" which data columns are which. For that, my plan was a count. I would count how many nonempty values each column has and then count how many of those nonempty values match each of the six possible columns. From there, I can take a simple ratio to determine the likelihood that the data contained is of that particular type. There would be some overvaluing of columns that are not unique, but in general, it is working nicely. The problem is that it is very slow.

I created a metadata table that I am calling UploadedTableColumn which contains every column header of the source file and which column it maps to in the database. Here is my stored procedure to update the counts:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE stored_Procedure 
    @FileLoadID INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SqlCommand NVARCHAR(MAX)

    DECLARE the_cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR 
    SELECT N'UPDATE UploadedTableColumn SET NumberNonemptyRows = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + DestinationTableName + N' WHERE ISNULL(' + DestinationColumnName + N','''') <> ''''),' + CHAR(13)
        + N'NumberID1Rows = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + DestinationTableName + N' WHERE ISNULL(' + DestinationColumnName + N','''') IN (SELECT ID1 FROM ID1Table) AND ISNULL(' + DestinationColumnName + N','''') <> ''''),' + CHAR(13)
        + N'NumberID2Rows = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + DestinationTableName + N' WHERE ISNULL(' + DestinationColumnName + N','''') IN (SELECT ID2 FROM ID2Table) AND ISNULL(' + DestinationColumnName + N','''') <> ''''),' + CHAR(13)
        + N'NumberIDDateRows = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + DestinationTableName + N' WHERE IIF(ISDATE(' + DestinationColumnName + N')=1,IIF(CAST(' + DestinationColumnName + N' AS DATE) IN (SELECT IDDate FROM IDDateTable),1,0),0) = 1 AND ISNULL(' + DestinationColumnName + N','''') <> ''''),' + CHAR(13)
        + N'NumberID4Rows = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + DestinationTableName + N' WHERE ISNULL(' + DestinationColumnName + N', '''') IN (SELECT ID4 FROM ID4Table) AND ISNULL(' + DestinationColumnName + N','''') <> ''''),' + CHAR(13)
        + N'NumberID5Rows = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + DestinationTableName + N' WHERE ISNULL(' + DestinationColumnName + N', '''') IN (SELECT ID5 FROM ID5Table) AND ISNULL(' + DestinationColumnName + N','''') <> ''''),' + CHAR(13)
        + N'NumberID6Rows = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + DestinationTableName + N' WHERE ISNULL(' + DestinationColumnName + N', '''') IN (SELECT ID6 FROM ID6Table) AND ISNULL(' + DestinationColumnName + N','''') <> '''')' + CHAR(13)
        + N'WHERE DestinationTableName = ''' + DestinationTableName + N''' AND DestinationColumnName = ''' + DestinationColumnName + N''' AND FileLoadID = ' + CAST(@FileLoadID AS NVARCHAR) + N';' + CHAR(13) As SqlCommand
    FROM UploadedTableColumn
    WHERE FileLoadID = @FileLoadID

    OPEN the_cursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM the_cursor
    INTO @SqlCommand

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE(@SqlCommand)

        FETCH NEXT FROM the_cursor 
        INTO @SqlCommand
    END

    CLOSE the_cursor
    DEALLOCATE the_cursor
END
```

Is there a faster approach?

Comment: For a similar problem I went different way. I stored the column name mapping of previous imports and suggested the best matching mapping for new imports.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes That was the idea behind the previous design. Unfortunately, even when we receive two files from a single source, we have found that the column headers and column orders (while similar) are not identical. One time, we got a file where the headers were stripped entirely. They refused to resend a corrected file, and we wound up having to use these counts to figure out what headers to give each column. It wasted about a week of time for one file! But, it is a great idea, and I wish I could use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One small change that might help.

You say you're holding every column of the source table in UploadedTableColumn - you don't need to do that, your cursor is looping through a lot of unnecessary columns. You can eliminate a lot with a pre-emptive column name match.

So get a combined list of all possible ID columns from your ID1Table, ID2Table, etc, and only pull into UploadedTableColumn the ones that actually match a column in DestinationTableName.

On the basis that there are probably no more than 6 columns in your source data that have a matching ID column name, you're now only checking those rather than all 100+.

Of course, this doesn't help you if you've got people sending data without headers and no agreed format.

Pseudo code to get the desired columns:

```
SELECT name
FROM sys.columns
WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('DestinationTableName')
AND Name IN
(
SELECT ID1 AS IDColumn FROM ID1Table
UNION ALL
SELECT ID2 AS IDColumn FROM ID2Table
...
)
```

Comment: That's an awesome idea! While I don't think that would specifically help, limiting the number of columns that I try searching through is a great idea. One of the fields I am checking against has a fixed number of characters for every entry. Also, I can limit the number of fields I am trying to match to by using where the source data is coming from and adding some filters to the data I am matching it against. I was so hyperfocused on how terrible the data was coming in that I forgot how I could use the fact that our data is fairly clean.

Comment: To follow up, I added the filter for the column that is a fixed length, and that alone already saved several seconds from the process. As I keep adding filters, I am pretty sure I can get the process to take only a few seconds, so I am marking this as the answer. Thanks again!